# How can I request only DB records created within the last day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The table does have the default `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. I've Googled this problem, but can't seem to work it out. I want to say something like `Review.where(created_at > Time.now - 24 hours)` or something like that. What's the simplest/smartest way to do that?

Comment: Last day? you mean yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all records that are created yesterday,you can do like this

```
Review.find(:all, :conditions => ["DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today-1])
```

**OR**

```
Review.where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Date.today - 1)
```

Comment: i have already given answer, what you add new in this.you just follow my answer an create another one.

Comment: @Bharatsoni Our answers are totally different.

Comment: No it's just copy of my answer.

Comment: @How could you say that?Dont you see the difference?

Comment: @Bharatsoni I know that.i can see.Its not you

Comment: @Bharatsoni @pavan Guys he is saying that he does not have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in `Review` table, How you can give answers like this.

Comment: @PramodShinde He does have. Infact every default `Rails migrations` has those `columns`.Read the Question carefully.

Comment: Just a small note, it's better to get used to the where method. The old hash finder is deprecated in 4.1. http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in reading question @pavan your answer in correct

Comment: @Iceman Yes it is deprecated in Rails 4.1. Unless the OP hasn't mentioned the version of Rails,both are valid Queries.

Comment: Indeed in pre 4.1, but for forward-compatibility it's better to use the where method.

Answer (score 0):

The following will help you for your problem

rails 2

```
YourModelName.all :conditions => ["DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", DateTime.now - 1]
```

rails 3

```
YourModelName.where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", DateTime.now - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

`Review.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 24.hours)`

This will return Reviews created in last 24 hours

Comment: This doesn't return results within the last day.

Comment: this returns results within last 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Indeed more elegant way in Rails 3

```
Review.where('created_at > ? ', Time.now - 1.day) #compares date and time as well 
Review.where('created_at > ? ', Date.today - 1) #compares only date
```